# How to modify a module installed from marketplace?

Tags: magento2

there are some behaviors in a module that i installed from Marketplace that i want to change a bit, like adding some more configurations, overriding template files and add a bit more Javascript, stylings, etc. I'm not seeing anywhere i can extend from a 3rd party module installed from Marketplace, what would be the best practices to deal with this? As i don't really want to modify the extension's code. I'm using Magento 2

Comment: what is your module name ? ( check registration.php file )

Comment: Assuming the module is called 'myworkspace/mymodulename'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check module name in registration.php and create same folder in your theme.

Inside this folder create 3 other folders ( templates, layout, web ). Now which ever file you want to change place in there and it will override module templates, layouts , js and css.

Note : view/frontend/templates file will go into templates folder. view/frontend/layouts will go in layout folder and web files in web/js and css files in web/css.

Here is helpful post to explain how to overrides templates and modules files :

https://jamersan.com/super-guide-theming-magento-2-part-2-3/

Comment: Hi can you help giving some links or articles about this? the modules i installed are through composer, so the codes are placed in vendor directory

Comment: Updated answer with a blog post url